# How to make stanza lemmatizer to return just the lemma instead of a dictionary?

Tags: python, nlp, stanford-nlp, lemmatization

I'm implementing stanza's lemmatizer because it works well with spanish texts but the lemmatizer retuns a whole dictionary with ID and other characteristics I don't care about for the time being. I checked the "processors" in the pipeline but I don't seem to find and example where I just get the sence with the lemmatized text instead of the dictionary.

This is what I have:

```
stanza.download('es', package='ancora', processors='tokenize,mwt,pos,lemma', verbose=False)
stNLP = stanza.Pipeline(processors='tokenize,mwt,pos,lemma', lang='es', use_gpu=True)
stNLP('me hubiera gustado mas “sincronia” con la primaria')
```

Output:

```
[
  [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "text": "me",
      "lemma": "yo",
      "upos": "PRON",
      "xpos": "pp1cs000",
      "feats": "Case=Dat|Number=Sing|Person=1|PrepCase=Npr|PronType=Prs",
      "start_char": 0,
      "end_char": 2
    },
....
```

Of course when I try to lemmatize my document it returns a lot of text I don't need at the moment, how can I just obtain the lemma? I'm aware I could possibly extract the word from the dictionary but it takes a lot of time as it is, what I want to avoid is giving the fuction extra work.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: simply use `for`-loops or `[index]` and `[key]` to get elements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure yet, but from what I've seen, it appears that Stanza's pipeline generates a nested structure in which each sentence is a list of tokens, and each token is akin to a dictionary containing various attributes such as ID, text, lemma, and so on.

It is easy to extract the lemmas by navigating this nested structure. Here's how I've done it.

```
stanza.download('es', package='ancora', processors='tokenize,mwt,pos,lemma', verbose=False)
stNLP = stanza.Pipeline(processors='tokenize,mwt,pos,lemma', lang='es', use_gpu=True)
doc = stNLP('me hubiera gustado mas “sincronia” con la primaria')
lemmas = [word.lemma for t in doc.iter_tokens() for word in t.words]
```

Note: As of the time of writing, the version of Stanza being used is stanza==1.7.0